# Bad request using checkbox with React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, bad-request

I'm having a problem posting a form data with axios (bad request 400). I found out that the error occurs only if a checkbox field is marked. If I don't use the checkboxes, the form post is fine.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Here is the field code:

```
<Form.Check className="campo-6" type="checkbox" label="Seg" name="AulaSegunda" onChange={onChange}/>
```

The oneChange method:

```
function onChange(ev) {
    const { name, value } = ev.target;
    setValues({...values, [name]: value});
  }
```

Axios post and configuration method:

```
let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {          
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'       
    }
  };

async function CadastrarAluno(JsonData){
  console.log(JsonData);
  await axios.post('https://localhost:52446/api/Alunos',JsonData,axiosConfig) 
  console.log(JsonData);
}
```

Network console tab after posting,
[image: network panel screenshot]